# Difference between static variable of C and of C++?

Tags: c++, c, static, non-static

In C it is an error

```
int x=5;
static int y=x; //error
```

In C++ it is valid why?

```
int x=5;
static int y=x; //valid
```

Comment: Well, according to Clang, *error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant*. I'd wager C requires the initializer to be a compile-time constant.

Comment: Because C++ can do a _lot_ of things that C can't, and C can do a few things that C++ can't.  They're different languages.

Answer (score 5):

Because C and C++ are different languages.

C++ has a *dynamic initialisation* stage when the program starts, in which static variables can be initialised using either non-trivial constructors or non-constant initialisers. C doesn't, and requires static variables to be initialised with constant expressions.

Comment: why C didn't include such feature . I mean what changes they have done in C to achieve this feature . Because in C and C++ both , static variables are loading time entity . Isn't it?

Comment: Both C and C++ have a *static initialisation* stage - what you might call "loading time". C++ added a *dynamic initialisation* stage after that; C didn't. It has benefits (more convenient initialisation) and problems (the initialisation order fiasco). In C++, it's pretty much needed, since otherwise you couldn't use non-trivial class types for static variables at all; so that benefit was deemed to outweigh the problems. In C, there's no particularly compelling reason to allow that rather than writing code in a function to set the initial value.